# Python Create an array of vectors

Tags: python

Basic question but I'm new to Python and I'd like to create an array of vectors. Unfortunately `arr.append()` isn't working...

Here's what I have:

```
for i, p in enumerate( someArr ):
    if x < y:
        locationArr = []
        location = obj.particle_systems[0].particles[i].location
        locationArr.append(location)
    return locationArr
```

Not sure what the location vector at `obj.particle_systems[0].particles[i].location` is ... object? Array? Output for an example is:
`Vector((1.0000001192092896, 0.9654528498649597, -0.4224875271320343))`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Duh, was defining the array in the for-loop

Comment: Yep.  Duh.  Reminds me of my very first scientific job right out of high school, at the Geophysical Institute.  Landsat images came down so fast it was striped across 4x 9-track tape drives then they sent us the tapes.  So on my first day they handed me a 3-inch stack of that 14 inch green-bar sprocket-fed line printer output of the FORTRAN program that put it all together into a single file.  And there was one particular situation where an entire line would take on the same value. It took an hour, but I found a variable being initialized right after the DO loop statement instead of before it.